# React Best Practices: Having properties other than `state` in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm reviewing a React Component and it contains a `state` property as well as an `allData` property.

To follow best practice, shouldn't `allData` be a part of `state`?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.allData = [];
    this.state = {
      allDisplayedData: [],
      allRowsCount: -1,
      favData: [],
      favRowsCount: -1,
    };

    this.searchAll = this.searchAll.bind(this);
    this.handleCellClick = this.handleCellClick.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: Does it change over time?

Comment: `allData` is populated in `componentDidMount()` once and it is used across different methods in the component. It does not mutate as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the component to re-render on changing it, then it needs to be in state, otherwise put it wherever. Any instance variables other than `this.state` aren't part of React's control, so they don't have the same ability to set using setState. This means that they don't re-render the component like the state does.

Essentially, it depends on what you do with it and how you want to work with it.

I tend to use this pattern for things like cancelTokens and intervalIds and other data I might need later, but don't need as part of the state because it's only needed in unmount or update but not in the render itself.

If it's needed in the render, you should have it in state or be prepared to deal with the component not rendering when it's updated.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the array part of state, then yes, if no, then no.

Comment: So there is no golden rule that says everything needs to be a part of a `this.state` property. We can have as many properties we want for the Component and it is not an anti-pattern?

Comment: Yes correct. It is almost inevitable that you'll declare variables in your component that aren't part of state.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the two previous detailed answers, I found the following statement at https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

> While this.props is set up by React itself and this.state has a
>   special meaning, you are free to add additional fields to the class
>   manually if you need to store something that doesn’t participate in
>   the data flow (like a timer ID).